# How get image icon desktop

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes

Using the code below, I get a pointer to the SysListView32 desktop, after requesting its members to get the icons:

```
import ctypes


def GetDesktopListViewHandle():
    import ctypes
    FindWindow = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW
    GetWindow = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindow

    def GetClassName(hwnd):
        buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(100)
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetClassNameW(hwnd, buff, 99)
        return buff.value

    from win32con import GW_CHILD

    hwnd = FindWindow('Progman', None)
    hwnd = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_CHILD)  # SHELLDLL_DefView
    hwnd = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_CHILD)  # SysListView32

    if GetClassName(hwnd) != 'SysListView32':
        return 0

    return hwnd


def ListView_GetItemCount(hwnd):
    import commctrl
    import ctypes
    SendMessage = ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW

    return SendMessage(hwnd, commctrl.LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0)


class LVITEMW(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('mask', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('iItem', ctypes.c_int32),
        ('iSubItem', ctypes.c_int32),
        ('state', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('stateMask', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('pszText', ctypes.c_uint64),
        ('cchTextMax', ctypes.c_int32),
        ('iImage', ctypes.c_int32),
        ('lParam', ctypes.c_uint64),  # On 32 bit should be c_long
        ('iIndent', ctypes.c_int32),
        ('iGroupId', ctypes.c_int32),
        ('cColumns', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('puColumns', ctypes.c_uint64),
        ('piColFmt', ctypes.c_int64),
        ('iGroup', ctypes.c_int32),
    ]


def get_desktop_image_icon(index):
    import struct
    import ctypes
    from commctrl import LVIF_IMAGE, LVM_GETITEMW
    from win32con import PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, MEM_RESERVE, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE, MEM_RELEASE

    GetWindowThreadProcessId = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId
    SendMessage = ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW
    OpenProcess = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess
    VirtualAllocEx = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAllocEx
    WriteProcessMemory = ctypes.windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory
    ReadProcessMemory = ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
    VirtualFreeEx = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualFreeEx
    CloseHandle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle

    MAX_LEN = 4096

    try:
        hwnd = GetDesktopListViewHandle()
        pid = ctypes.create_string_buffer(4)
        p_pid = ctypes.addressof(pid)
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, p_pid)

        h_process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, struct.unpack("i", pid)[0])

        copied = ctypes.create_string_buffer(4)
        p_copied = ctypes.addressof(copied)

        lvitem = LVITEMW()
        lvitem.mask = ctypes.c_uint32(LVIF_IMAGE)
        lvitem.iItem = ctypes.c_int32(index)
        lvitem.iSubItem = ctypes.c_int32(0)

        p_buffer_lvi = VirtualAllocEx(h_process, 0, MAX_LEN, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)
        WriteProcessMemory(h_process, p_buffer_lvi, ctypes.addressof(lvitem), ctypes.sizeof(LVITEMW), p_copied)

        SendMessage(hwnd, LVM_GETITEMW, 0, p_buffer_lvi)
        ReadProcessMemory(h_process, p_buffer_lvi, ctypes.addressof(lvitem), ctypes.sizeof(LVITEMW), p_copied)
        return lvitem.iImage

    finally:
        try:
            VirtualFreeEx(h_process, p_buffer_lvi, 0, MEM_RELEASE)
        except:
            pass

        try:
            CloseHandle(h_process)
        except:
            pass
```

And when you run the code, get some going, with whom I do not know what can be done:

```
print(get_desktop_image_icon(0))  # 11
print(get_desktop_image_icon(1))  # 12
print(get_desktop_image_icon(2))  # 13
```

**Update:**

Assuming that `get_desktop_image_icon` function returns the indices the `ImageList`, I used the code below to get at the handle of the `ImageList` `ListView` desktop, and `ImageList` request icons in the indices, but they do not come back. Prompt, in what could be the problem and how to solve it?

```
print(get_desktop_image_icon(0))  # 11
print(get_desktop_image_icon(1))  # 12
print(get_desktop_image_icon(2))  # 13

hwnd = GetDesktopListViewHandle()
print(hwnd)  # 65784

from commctrl import LVSIL_NORMAL, ILD_IMAGE
h_il = ListView_GetImageList(hwnd, LVSIL_NORMAL)
print(h_il)  # 860139888

from win32gui import ImageList_GetIcon
print(ImageList_GetIcon(h_il, 0, ILD_IMAGE))  # 0
print(ImageList_GetIcon(h_il, 11, ILD_IMAGE))  # 0


# typedef struct _IMAGEINFO {
#   HBITMAP hbmImage;
#   HBITMAP hbmMask;
#   int     Unused1;
#   int     Unused2;
#   RECT    rcImage;
# } IMAGEINFO, *LPIMAGEINFO;

import ctypes.wintypes
class IMAGEINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('hbmImage', ctypes.wintypes.HBITMAP),
        ('hbmMask', ctypes.wintypes.HBITMAP),
        ('Unused1', ctypes.c_int),
        ('Unused2', ctypes.c_int),
        ('rcImage', ctypes.wintypes.RECT),
    ]

ImageList_GetImageInfo = ctypes.windll.comctl32.ImageList_GetImageInfo
# BOOL ImageList_GetImageInfo(
#    HIMAGELIST himl,
#    int        i,
#    IMAGEINFO  *pImageInfo
# );

pImageInfo = IMAGEINFO()
print(ImageList_GetImageInfo(h_il, 0, ctypes.byref(pImageInfo)))  # 0
print(ImageList_GetImageInfo(h_il, 11, ctypes.byref(pImageInfo)))  # 0
```

How can i get the icon and save them?

Comment: Could you provide a little more context to your question? What is a desktop image icon?

Comment: LVITEMV describes an element of the desktop (icon). Do icons have an image that should be in iImage. So I want to get it and keep

Comment: The icon will be in the system image list, but the problem is that the indices can be different for each process. I think you'll need to inject code and do this in-process.

Comment: why do you import `ctypes` in every class if you already did it in the first line?

Comment: @Aemyl, function to become independent, and imports always happens once. Now I'm not sure what the correct way to do :)