# How to get file thumbnail from windows cache through python?

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes, thumbnails, pywin32

Goal is to get files thumbnails from selected folder on windows in a minimum possible amount of time.

Imagemagick and other tools open files every time, so they may not be the most efficient. Built-in mechanism in Windows has a possibility that the thumbnails can be in cache, which theoretically gives a considerable speed boost.

From [How to get thumbnail of file using the Windows API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523599/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-file-using-the-windows-api) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19529633/7213505)) it became clear about the ways, but there was a lot of problems:

- [IThumbnailProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774614(v=vs.85).aspx) and [IThumbnailCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774628(v=vs.85).aspx) not found in:

  1. ctypes.windll.shell32 (there is only functions, and seems that there is no simple way to get interfaces)
  2. win32com.shell.shell (PyWin32)
- [IID_IThumbnailProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774614(v=vs.85).aspx) and [IShellItemImageFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761084(v=vs.85).aspx) through [SHCreateItemFromParsingName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762134(v=vs.85).aspx) and IID:

  1. That IID's not found in win32com.shell.shell, so they was provided manually.
  2. [IThumbnailProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774614(v=vs.85).aspx), [IShellItem::BindToHandler method](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitem-bindtohandler#bhid_thumbnailhandler): fixed, but now error is the same as below:

     ```
     # str(shell.IID_IShellItem) == '{43826D1E-E718-42EE-BC55-A1E261C37BFE}'
     # str(shell.BHID_ThumbnailHandler) == '{7B2E650A-8E20-4F4A-B09E-6597AFC72FB0}'

     item = shell.SHCreateItemFromParsingName(r'd:\some.png', None, str(shell.IID_IShellItem))  # str() is works
     IID_IThumbnailProvider = '{e357fccd-a995-4576-b01f-234630154e96}'
     provider = item.BindToHandler(None, shell.BHID_ThumbnailHandler, IID_IThumbnailProvider)  # error

     > TypeError: 'There is no interface object registered that supports this IID'
     ```
  3. [IShellItemImageFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761084(v=vs.85).aspx): suspect that there is wrong usage of IID, but from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19529633/7213505) below it should work:

     ```
     IID_IShellItemImageFactory = '{bcc18b79-ba16-442f-80c4-8a59c30c463b}'
     item = shell.SHCreateItemFromParsingName(r'd:\some.png', None, IID_IShellItemImageFactory)  # error

     > TypeError: 'There is no interface object registered that supports this IID'
     ```

It would be great to understand how to swim in all this without learning the whole winapi..

Thanks in advance.

Windows 10 (20H2), Python 3.9.5, PyWin32 301

---

Update: Found answer about PyWin32 ([pythoncom.CoCreateInstance can't create IZoneIdentifier; the interface is missing from registry too despite being documented in MSDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453455/pythoncom-cocreateinstance-cant-create-izoneidentifier-the-interface-is-missin)). In short, these interfaces are not implemented. Checked by:

```
> import pythoncom
> pythoncom.InterfaceNames
```

So .. there are 2 questions left. Are there any options to get to thumbnails without using PyWin32? Via ctypes, for example. And how?

Comment: [BHID_ThumbnailHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitem-bindtohandler#bhid_thumbnailhandler): *"Restricts usage to `IExtractImage` or `IThumbnailProvider`."*

Comment: Thanks, attentiveness let down.

Comment: Are you sure you can specify IID as a string like that?  In C/C++ it's generally a binary structure.

Comment: Your code 3. works fine with C++. The problem comes from python (how you use win32com.shell).

Comment: @MarkRansom, yes, str(shell.IID_IShellItem) above is works correctly.

Comment: @SimonMourier, thanks for check, then the problem is on the side of PyWin32.. code fragments above use that import:
    from win32com.shell import shell

Comment: Sure maybe that one case works correctly, but doesn't it occur to you that a function ending with `ParsingName` might be doing extra work because it expects a string as input?

Comment: Have a look at [python: how to convert a valid uuid from String to UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15859156/5987), maybe it will help.

Comment: @MarkRansom, thanks for advices, but reason is that it not implemented in PyWin32.. Question was updated.

Comment: The simplest way would be to write a python module in C or  make a pull request to win32com.shell which is missing IShellItemImageFactory, IThumbnailProvider, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here some working Python 3 code based on ctypes and comtypes:

```
from ctypes import POINTER, byref, cast, windll, c_void_p, c_wchar_p
from ctypes.wintypes import SIZE, UINT, HANDLE, HBITMAP
from comtypes import GUID, IUnknown, COMMETHOD, HRESULT

shell32 = windll.shell32
shell32.SHCreateItemFromParsingName.argtypes = [c_wchar_p, c_void_p, POINTER(GUID), POINTER(HANDLE)]
shell32.SHCreateItemFromParsingName.restype = HRESULT

SIIGBF_RESIZETOFIT = 0

class IShellItemImageFactory(IUnknown):
    _case_insensitive_ = True
    _iid_ = GUID('{bcc18b79-ba16-442f-80c4-8a59c30c463b}')
    _idlflags_ = []

IShellItemImageFactory._methods_ = [
    COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'GetImage',
        ( ['in'], SIZE, 'size' ),
        ( ['in'], UINT, 'flags' ),
        ( ['out'], POINTER(HBITMAP), 'phbm' )),
    ]

LP_IShellItemImageFactory = POINTER(IShellItemImageFactory)

def get_thumbnail(filename, icon_size):
    ''' Returns thumbnail image as HBITMAP'''
    h_siif = HANDLE()
    hr = shell32.SHCreateItemFromParsingName(filename, 0,
            byref(IShellItemImageFactory._iid_), byref(h_siif))
    if hr < 0:
        raise Exception(f'SHCreateItemFromParsingName failed: {hr}')
    h_siif = cast(h_siif, LP_IShellItemImageFactory)
    # Raises exception on failure.
    return h_siif.GetImage(SIZE(icon_size, icon_size), SIIGBF_RESIZETOFIT)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    h_bitmap = get_thumbnail(r'C:\test\test.jpg', 64)
    print(h_bitmap)
```

Comment: Seems that half of work is done, and code is really seems to work. But result is not image.. If i understand correctly - need some code to get it from windows structure, like in answer update [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046458/how-get-image-icon-desktop)

Comment: @C0oo1D You can convert the returned HBITMAP into a PIL image object by using CreateCompatibleDC, SelectObject and GetDIBits (all implemented by windll.gdi32) and then finally Image.frombytes("RGBA", (icon_size, icon_size), bits, "raw", "BGRA").
But I think this would be too much extra code to add it to my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used user15566053's solution to obtain the h_bitmap handle but could not manage to retrieve the actual image with his suggestion (using CreateCompatibleDC, SelectObject...).

However, the following method did work:

```
from PIL import Image
import win32ui
...
h_bitmap = get_thumbnail(r'C:\test\test.jpg', 128)
pyCBitmap = win32ui.CreateBitmapFromHandle(h_bitmap)  # Returns a PyCBitmap
info = pyCBitmap.GetInfo()  # Get a dictionary with info about the image (including width and height)
data = pyCBitmap.GetBitmapBits(True)
pil_image = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (info['bmWidth'], info['bmHeight']), data, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)
pil_image.show()
```

Warning: shell32.SHCreateItemFromParsingName() can't handle file paths with '/'. Make sure you convert them to '\'.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to use above answers to convert a thumbnail to a Numpy array and then to a QImage and QPixmap to use in a Qt6 GUI.

```
import numpy as np
from PySide6 import QtGui
# ...
h_bitmap = get_thumbnail(path, self.size)
pyCBitmap = win32ui.CreateBitmapFromHandle(h_bitmap)
info = pyCBitmap.GetInfo()
w, h = info['bmWidth'], info['bmHeight']
data = pyCBitmap.GetBitmapBits(True)
arr = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(h, w, 4)
image = QtGui.QImage(arr.data, w, h, w * 4, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32).copy()
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
```